# javascript Google maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map on my website.
Everything works (user name as well as the description and showing the route on the map) and i have a little marker on the map. But i cannot get this marker to move. I have a distance in my function

> o.user.distance = o.user.distance || 0,

with a value of 0 and whenever i change the 0 to another number the map crashes and doesnt a route or marker anymore.
I have the following code:

```
    function initialize(o) {
        r = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //-> Opties
        o = o || {};
        //-> Controles uitvoeren

        o.zoom = o.zoom || 13,
//            o.center = o.center || new google.maps.LatLng(51.333333, 3.816667),
            o.center = o.center || new google.maps.LatLng(15.111901287412248, 145.68626403808594),
            o.maptype = o.maptype || google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            o.origin = o.origin || 'Terneuzen',
            o.destination = o.destination || 'Santiago de Compostela, A Coruna, Spanje',
            o.travelmode = o.travelmode || google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
            //-> Route controles
            o.route = o.route || {},
            o.route.color = o.route.color || '#40403f',
            o.route.weight = o.route.weight || 3,
            //-> Afgelegde route controles
            o.traveled = o.traveled || {},
            o.traveled.color = o.traveled.color || '#e6007e',
            o.traveled.weight = o.traveled.weight || 4,
            //-> User
            o.user = o.user || {},
            o.user.name = o.user.name || '<?php echo $user->user_nicename ?>',
            o.user.distance = o.user.distance || 0,
            o.user.description = o.user.description || '<?php echo $user->user_stappen . ' Stappen gelopen'?>',
            //-> Other users
            o.others = o.others || {};

        //-> Opties
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: o.zoom,
            mapTypeId: o.maptype,
            center: o.center,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        }

        var el = document.getElementById("map");

        if (el != null) {
            //-> Map maken
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        }

        //-> Route bouwen
        calcRoute(o);
    }
```

Does anyone know why i cannot change the distance or how i fix this issue?

I am using the following api call:

```
<script async defer src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=(I have a working correct key here)&callback=initialize" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of crash do you mean? If you have any error message, please show it here.

Comment: @IzumiSy The map wont show the route or the marker anymore and i get this error in the console log https://i.gyazo.com/decbf581d6dbb2098b38bacb17e8ef2a.png

Comment: Where are you using the value of `o.user.distance` in your project?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem